# Supress duplicate entries in argaparse generated 'help' text

Tags: python, argparse

My question is about how to suppress or change some auto-generated text in the output of argaparse when using the `-h` argument to show the help. The issue that I experience is that a few unwanted and duplicate entries appear. My reason for asking here is that I am unable to find an explanation in the Python and argaparse documentation that explains to me why this text appears and how to get rid of it.

I have a small script called "sbucalc" that includes the following lines of code:

```
parser=argparse.ArgumentParser('calculates the NWO initial grant and the RCCS credits for a given amount of SBU', usage='sbucalc [-h][--nwo INITIAL PERCENT] [--rccs SBU RATE]')
parser.add_argument('--nwo', nargs='+', help='--nwo INITIAL_GRANT [PERCENT] default=10')
parser.add_argument('--rccs', nargs='+',  help='--rccs SBU [RATE] default=1.14')
parser.print_help
```

What I get when I execute `sbucalc -h` is:

```
usage: calculates the NWO initial grant and the RCCS credits for a given amount of SBU [-h][--nwo INITIAL PERCENT] [--rccs SBU RATE]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --nwo NWO [NWO ...]   --nwo INITIAL_GRANT [PERCENT] default=10
  --rccs RCCS [RCCS ...]
                        --rccs SBU [RATE] default=1.14
```

I don't seem to find a way to suppress these first instances of `--nwo NWO [NWO...]` the desired result should be:

```
usage: calculates the NWO initial grant and the RCCS credits for a given amount of SBU [-h][--nwo INITIAL PERCENT] [--rccs SBU RATE]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --nwo INITIAL_GRANT [PERCENT] default=10
  --rccs SBU [RATE] default=1.14
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

> P.D.: I understand why the term "help" cannot be used in the title,
> but when your question is about the freakin' output of the help
> message, this restriction is not really something that you want to
> have.

Comment: They are cause by the `nargs='+'` which allows one or more values for the argument.

Comment: To echo Klaus's comment: if you want to allow for multiple initial grant values, use the '+'. The extra [NWO ...] is there to help the user indicate that multiple grant values are allowed. If you want to use just one value, set `nargs` to 1 (or don't use it, and leave it at its default). Same for rccs, of course. If you want yet something else, please indicate this in your question.

Comment: The left column is autogenerated.  You can tweak it with the `metavar` parameter, but not eliminate it.  Rewrite the help text with that in mind.  Anything else requires a subclassed help formatter.

Comment: For `argparse` questions we like to see sample command line(s) and desired `args` result.  In other words, what you parse is as important, if not more so, than the help format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for something like

```py
import argparse

parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description='calculates the NWO initial grant and the RCCS credits for a given amount of SBU',
    usage='sbucalc [-h] [--nwo INITIAL PERCENT] [--rccs SBU RATE]')
parser.add_argument(
    '--nwo', dest='initial_grant', nargs=1, help='[PERCENT] default=10')
parser.add_argument(
    '--rccs', dest='sbu', nargs=1, help='[RATE] default=1.14')
parser.print_help()
```

This results in

```
usage: sbucalc [-h] [--nwo INITIAL PERCENT] [--rccs SBU RATE]

calculates the NWO initial grant and the RCCS credits for a given amount of
SBU

optional arguments:
  -h, --help           show this help message and exit
  --nwo INITIAL_GRANT  [PERCENT] default=10
  --rccs SBU           [RATE] default=1.14
```

Notice how the variables are named so that the help message includes the descriptive name you say you want, and how I changed `nargs='+'` - which apparently you did not really want here anyway - to `nargs=1` which marks the option as non-optional. (This is oxymoronic, and should generally be avoided. If an argument isn't optional, make it a required argument, though perhaps with a facility for *alternatively* specifying it as an option. `nargs='?'` does this.)

Oh, and I added the missing `description` keyword to include the description in the output.

... Though if you really want there to be a default, these options should not be mandatory, and you should use the `default` keyword to specify the actual default.

```py
parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description='calculates the NWO initial grant and the RCCS credits for a given amount of SBU',
    usage='sbucalc [options]',
    formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
parser.add_argument(
    '--nwo', dest='initial_grant', default=10, help='[PERCENT]')
parser.add_argument(
    '--rccs', dest='sbu', default=1.14, help='[RATE]')
```

which prints

```
usage: sbucalc [-h] [options]

calculates the NWO initial grant and the RCCS credits for a given amount of
SBU

optional arguments:
  -h, --help           show this help message and exit
  --nwo INITIAL_GRANT  [PERCENT] (default: 10)
  --rccs SBU           [RATE] (default: 1.14)
```

(Notice also the `formatter_class` argument to the initializer.)

Specifying the options in the `usage` message is really just adding more duplication and creating another maintenance hassle; a better convention is to just have the user refer to the options listing below, and keep a simple `usage='sbucalc [options]'` or something like that, like I do here.

(Finally, notice also how you forgot the parentheses around the `print_help()` function call.)

Comment: Thanks! The whole aim of the above code was actually to learn how to use argparse, it's not production code or similar. So, as an exercise I am trying to re-write a few simple bash scripts in Python. But I really got bogged down with the documentation. BTW, the parenthesis in the print() function are there in the original, I swear  0:)